# Excel headers/footers won't change via VBA unless blank

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Disclaimer: It's been a few years since I worked (a lot) with VBA, so this might be an issue caused by confusing myself with what is essentially a very different language from what I usually deal with.

So; I've got a workbook (Excel 2010) with multiple sheets (20+), most of whom are multi-page. To make things easier when printing everything, I want to add some sheet-specific headers with amongst others the name of the sheet, number of pages and so on.

I've written a tiny function that should (in theory) do this for me by iterating over all the sheets setting the header. However, for some reason it only works if the header is empty; if it already has a value it refuses to overwrite for some unknown reason.

```
Dim sheetIndex, numsheets As Integer
sheetIndex = 1
numsheets = Sheets.Count

' Loop through each sheet, but don't set any of them to active
While sheetIndex <= numsheets
    Dim sheetname, role, labeltext As String
    sheetname = Sheets(sheetIndex).name
    role = GetRole(mode) 
    labeltext = "Some text - " & sheetname & " - " & role

    With Sheets(sheetIndex).PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = labeltext
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = "Page &[Page] / &[Pages]"
        .LeftFooter = "&[Date] - &[Time]"
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = "Page &P / &N"
    End With

    sheetIndex = sheetIndex + 1
Wend
```

Comment: Very strange behavior.  I can duplicate your problem in Excel 2010.  Even if I record a macro while I manually change the header, then run that macro, it will not work properly.  Seemingly random behavior about adding portions of the header text.

Comment: Yeah, I've also had some issues when adding pagenumbers to other parts of the header; for some reason Excel removes part of the magic words (replacing eg. &[Pages] with &[Pa) thus making the whole header useless. This only happens when the header is edited by a macro, eg. if it changes LeftHeader it will also mess up RightHeader

Comment: I doubt it's anything to do with your issue, but make sure you do a find and replace on the *role* text for characters that need to be escaped in header text (ampersand comes to mind which needs to be doubled up as &&) if there is any chance they are in there (like "Packaging & Distribution" as a role..)

Comment: pnuts, Cor_Blimey: No difference, GetRole returns a simple string with no special characters. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work for replacing text.  For whatever reason, in the macro, you need to include the [header/footer format character codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb225426%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in order for it to work properly.

This code worked to replace existing header text with new information:

```
Sub test()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Worksheets(1)
    sht.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&L left text"
    sht.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&C center Text"
    sht.PageSetup.RightHeader = "&R right text"
End Sub
```

Without the `&L`, `&C`, and `&R` codes before the text, I could not get it to work.

Some interesting behavior I found is that if you use the following code:

```
.CenterHeader = "&L some text"
```

it will actually put the `some text` in the `LeftHeader` position.  This led me to believe that the formatting codes were very important.

Answer (score 7):

The line `Application.PrintCommunication = False` (which is added by the macro recorder) before doing PageSetup screws up the formating via VBA.

If your code has got this line in it, try removing it. That solved my problem with setting the header and footer via VBA.

Comment: Thanks! This is the right answer since I was also keeping that recorded line. As soon as I removed that line the macro started to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I've read StackOverflow for years and this is the first time I've actually been able to post a solution ... hope it helps someone!!  Also, you need to remember, I am a CPA not a programmer ;-)

I am reading some values from the ActiveSheet to populate the header.  The application is a tax election that will be sent with a tax return so it must have the taxpayer's name and social security number at the top.

```
Sub PrintElection()
' Print preview the MTM Election
    If Range("Tax_Year").Value = Range("First_MTM_year").Value Then
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = Format(Worksheets("Election").Range("Taxpayer_Name").Value)
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = Format(Worksheets("Election").Range("Taxpayer_SSN").Value)

        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintPreview

    Else

        MsgBox "The 'Effective For Tax Year' date must EQUAL the 'First MTM year' date", vbOKOnly, "Check Years"
        Sheets("Roadmap").Select
        Range("First_MTM_year").Select
   End If

End Sub
```

It checks to see if the Mark-to-Market election year is the same as the election form then formats the election page.

Answer (score 1):

I split the sheet print setup into 2 loops.  First loop with Application.PrintCommunication = False I run the non-header/footer setup.  I then set Application.PrintCommunication = True and run the header/footer setup in a second loop.  Appears to run faster than in XL2003, and applies the header/footer correctly.  Until MS fixes this bug, that works fine for me.